# Magento Ajax - How to get only body part?

Tags: ajax, magento

I am trying to use ajax call with Magento. When I call a block page via Ajax, I get all the HTML including head, css, javascript, and body. How do I get only body part?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you can provide a little more information about which "block page" you are calling it may be easier to discern the issue. By default, Magento includes the `<default>` layout tag for all pages, which will give you the page headers and footers even on AJAX calls.

To send a page without all that extra, you have a few options. Firstly, you can simple set the output manually on your own, avoiding the layout system entirely. Magento does this for the one-page checkout feature:

```
$result = array( 'foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar', );
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
```

You can also modify this method to use a custom layout handler like this:

```
protected function loadPage() {
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $update->load('your_custom_handle');
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();

    $result = array( 'outputHtml' => $output, 'otherVar' => 'foo', );
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));        
}
```

And in your layout file:

```
<your_custom_handle>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="module/block" name="root" output="toHtml" template="module/template.phtml"/>
</your_custom_handle>
```

A second option, if you want to use layouts, is to define an alternative default layout. When you call `$this->loadLayout();` in Magento controllers, you can actually specify a handle other than `<default>` to descend from. An example from the Magento product controller would be:

```
$this->loadLayout('popup');
```

This layout is defined by default within the `main.xml` layout file, and renders the `popup.phtml` template, and may be suitable for your use.

If you still have trouble, let me know and we can try other things. Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Note that if your copying and pasting the layout file example, make sure to change `type="module/block"` to an actual magento block type, like `type="page/html"`, or a custom block type defined for you module.

Comment: brilliant, simple, eficient... I love it. Thanks Joe

Comment: Just wanted to express the importance of 

    output="toHtml"


in the layout file. This is the code that will actually cause the layout to generate the html. If that was missing you would not get any html.

Comment: there is also a third approach http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/cannot-get-custom-frontend-ajax-layout-to-load

Comment: @Joseph does it work for magento 2.3 could you please provide file name for all your code